# ActiveRecord dirty ('_was') is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

```
# User.rb model:

before_save :simplify_errors

def simplify_errors
  if password_was.blank?
    ...
  end
end
```

#### Error

```
undefined method `was' for nil:NilClass
```

Rails 3.2.11, Ruby 2.0.0.

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Is your code above incorrect, or do you actually have `password.was.blank?`?

Comment: @CDub Apologies - my code says `password_was.blank?`